How to prevent programs from reading Chrome data?
I found a program on Github that can easily extract data from the installed browsers with just one command. This includes, localstorage, passwords etc. It doesn't need administrator access.
Is there a way to prevent programs (except chrome obviously) from accessing the chrome directory so that they cannot obtain this data? I'm using Windows.
Imo, it shouldn't be this easy to access this data.
Thanks.

It should be noted that as of today, Edge and Chrome don't offer good protection for their saved passwords (possibly this has changed when you use edge's new "wallet"). For example: if you set a master password for securing your passwords, 3rd party tools cann read the passwords without even knowing that master password. That pw will only be needed by the browser process itself, reducing the protective scenario to certain in-browser-attacks. Firefox however, will properly protect its passwords if you set a master password. It is beyond me why the chromium based browsers cannot do the same.

The basic restriction is that if one process, like Chrome, running in your logged-in user session with your user permissions can read the data (without asking for a password), then any other process you run can read it as well by following the same steps chrome does.
Chrome (and any chromium-based browser) already encrypts its local storage using your windows user credentials. You can go farther with one of these:

Enable the option to "Use Windows Hello when filling passwords", which does stop other processes from being able to read your passwords, but also requires you to sign in every time to access them yourself.
Run Chrome as a separate windows user account, which requires entering credentials on start. Nothing else you launch will be able to interact with it or its data unless they have admin rights (note: downloaded files will save to that user's folder by default). You can generally do this with shift+right-click > run as different user.


And of course, the primary ways to prevent malicious programs from reading your data, are to not run them in the first place or to not store that data locally at all.
